# Issue: DiscordJS App crashes when a command is run multiple times in a row

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been playing around with the Slash Commands options that DiscordJS added in V13. I have created my command and event handlers, and everything boots up just fine.

The current behavior is:

1.) Boots up with no problem. All confirmation messages load in console and commands are registered

2.) When running the /ping command for the first time in the Discord channel I received the below message
[Discord Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESK5P.png)

3.) When running the /ping command for the second time I get a successful response of "Pong!" in the channel I entered the command into

4.) When running the /ping command for the third time I get a successful response of "Pong!" but the bot crashes with the below error message

```
C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\bot\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:94
    if (this.deferred || this.replied) throw new Error('INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED');
                                             ^

Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
    at CommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\bot\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:94:46)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\bot\discordBot\events\interactionCreate.js:17:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED'
}
```

I am running out of ideas on how to resolve this. I have tried in the Ping command a number of reply options to the interaction but none have corrected the issue. Has anyone run into this?

I have a full code sample on my Github for review: https://github.com/DBAggie/discordBot/tree/dev

Comment: You might wanted to add some `setTimeout` as your cooldown. So when someone tried to spam your command, they can't spam it and preventing it to throw an error.

Comment: I tried adding a wait timer to the Ping command under the reply. Any suggestions on where else to put it?

Comment: I think that isn't the main reason.

Comment: I agree. The fact that it doesn't return a response on the first command is strange which is another thing I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Can you print error of [this](https://github.com/DBAggie/discordBot/blob/3efa35c6bbf7b74381bab56c7e75575b95d5034f/events/interactionCreate.js#L15)?
I think that's why it causes the fourth message.

Comment: There're already replied but errors after replies and it caught and tries to reply error message.

Comment: Giving it a shot now. One moment.

Comment: `The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.` because when the command used, even the bot didn't sent on time, then user used the command again. The interaction will be deferred

Comment: @ChangAlex Here is the result after your suggested change from the console output:

[link](https://github.com/DBAggie/discordBot/issues/2)

Comment: @新Acesyyy I understand that but, I am not sure what needs to happen to correct this. If the bot straight up crashes when this happens then I am trying to think of a way to handle it and ignore the command.

Comment: I'll download your git and do test.
Wait for my result.

Comment: @ChangAlex Look at the master branch for the config.json file. It is needed for the code to work.

Comment: I've posted my anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a few tests, I find where's the problem.
You just listen to the event again for every `interactionCreate` fired.

So first it won't respond. And listen for a new `interactionCreate` event.

## Before

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    execute(interaction, client) {
        client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
            console.log(`hit the interaction create script`)
            if (!interaction.isCommand()) return console.log('Not a valid command');

            const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

            if (!command) return;

            try {
                console.log('Trying to execute')
                await command.execute(interaction);
            } catch (error) {
                await interaction.reply({
                    content: 'There was an error while executing this command!',
                    ephemeral: true
                });
            }
            console.log('Below the catch');
        });
        //console.log('Below the below catch message');
    }
};
```

## After

```
module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        console.log(`hit the interaction create script`);
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return console.log("Not a valid command");

        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!command) return;

        try {
            console.log("Trying to execute");
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            await interaction.reply({
                content: "There was an error while executing this command!",
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        }
        console.log("Below the catch");
        //console.log('Below the below catch message');
    },
};
```

See here? You listen for a new event when every interaction.

```
execute(interaction, client) {
    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
```

Comment: BTW 
client id in config is unnecessary.
You can use client.user.id instead.